# How to run callemall material ui project?

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I have cloned the repository from "https://github.com/callemall/material-ui" and did the npm install now how to run the project so that I can do the POC with the components and check them in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it in a React project, material ui has an example project [with React](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v1-beta/examples/create-react-app).
If you already cloned the repository, run these commands to install and start up the project in your browser:

```
cd examples\create-react-app
npm install
npm run start
```